# TouchBar don't displayed NSViewController Storyboard

Tags: xcode, macos, storyboard, nstouchbar

I use Xcode 8.2.1 on macOS 10.12.3

I try to display element on TouchBar with my NSViewController but I can't do it... I have just drag&drop the TouchBar element on my NSViewController element in my Storyboard and add a label but this label is not displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to drag the TouchBar in the Window Controller, not the View Controller. Also make sure that your Window is initial controller.

PS
An information in some ways related with this question: when, in the view, there is a text field in focus, the standard touch bar will overwrite your customized touch bar. More information [here](http://www.joecieplinski.com/blog/2016/11/22/touch-bar-support-and-interface-builder/.%C2%A0).